# installation on RedHat without subscription-manager

Tags: redhat

Is there a way to install gcc-g++ (for example) without subscription-manager ?

```
sudo yum upgrade gcc-c++
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register
```

.

Comment: Use Fedora or AlmaLinux. You have to have some form of a subscription to use the RedHat repos on RedHat.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I can not switch now to Ubuntu. I am using an AMI that has only RedHat (AMI provided by the company)

Comment: Tell your company you need a RedHat subscription then. Don't think Ubuntu. AlmaLinux is based off of RedHat.

Answer (score 0):

You can create free account in RHN and register up to 15 machines [for free](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/faqs-no-cost-red-hat-enterprise-linux#system_registration).
Then (after register the machine) you can manage repos and install desired packages